# optional regex capture group - what am i missing?

Tags: regex, powershell

this is the code I'm testing

```
$counter = 0
@'
    1.1.1.1 (IMGTBCCWPRTIE34)
    2.2.2.2 (CMRI58672304 INC02394875 - fj)
'@.Split("`n") | % {
    $counter++
    if ($_ -match '((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?:-\d+)?).*?((?:IR |INC)\d+)?') {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Line = $counter
            IP = $Matches[1]
            Number = $Matches[2]
        }
    }
}
```

which gives me this, and i don't know why there is no number for the second line

```
Line IP      Number
---- --      ------
   1 1.1.1.1       
   2 2.2.2.2
```

and, of course, if i make the last part mandatory by removing the final `?`, the non matching line captures nothing

```
$counter = 0
@'
    1.1.1.1 (IMGTBCCWPRTIE34)
    2.2.2.2 (CMRI58672304 INC02394875 - fj)
'@.Split("`n") | % {
    $counter++
    if ($_ -match '((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?:-\d+)?).*?((?:IR |INC)\d+)') {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Line = $counter
            IP = $Matches[1]
            Number = $Matches[2]
        }
    }
}
```

gives me this

```
Line IP      Number     
---- --      ------     
   2 2.2.2.2 INC02394875
```

this works, but id like the regex to be all one one line

```
$counter = 0
@'
    1.1.1.1 (IMGTBCCWPRTIE34)
    2.2.2.2 (CMRI58672304 INC02394875 - fj)
'@.Split("`n") | % {
    $counter++
    if ($_ -match '((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?:-\d+)?)') {
        $ip = $Matches[1].Trim()
        if ($_ -match '((?:IR |INC)\d+)') {
            $number = $Matches[1].Trim()
        } else {
            $number = $null
        }
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Line = $counter
            IP = $ip
            Number = $number
        }
    }
}
```

and it gives me my desired result, but I'm not sure how to get here with just one regex.

```
Line IP      Number
---- --      ------
   1 1.1.1.1               
   2 2.2.2.2 INC02394875
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

here is where I'm testing

https://regex101.com/r/cP9wF2/1

Comment: What is the 4th question mark for in your original regex?  The one that comes after `.*`.  Trying to make it non-greedy?

Comment: i put that there to change it from a greedy capture to lazy. not sure if it made a difference because whether it's there or not, i get the same results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?:-\d+)?)(?:.*?((?:IR |INC)\d+))?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/cHyNDi0WQuy4M4kO)

The non-greedy modifier on `.*?` will cause it to stop matching as soon as it matches the space I think, assuming there's no later match.

So instead, we surround that whole second part from `.*?` through the optional capture group at the end, in a non-capturing group, and make *that* optional, while inside that, the (previously optional) capturing group is mandatory.

Comment: wow. masterful. i love it! this is really great information - thank you for your help :)

Comment: @AnthonyStringer thanks! this one had me scratching my head for a bit